# Ways to temporarily disable sticky in Semantic-UI-React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I can't find a prop like `isActive` in the [sticky document](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/sticky) that can disable the sticky easily like [react-sticky](https://github.com/captivationsoftware/react-sticky). Is it possible to do that in Semantic-UI-React sticky ?
I've tried making the `context` props null in `Sticky`, but it's still sticky when scroll.

Sticky code:

```
export default class StickyAdjacentContextExample extends Component {
  state = {}
  handleContextRef = contextRef => this.setState({ contextRef })

  render() {
    const { contextRef } = this.state

    return (
       <div ref={this.handleContextRef}>
             <Sticky context={contextRef}>
                  <Header as='h3'>Stuck Content</Header>
                  <Image src='/assets/images/wireframe/image.png' />
                </Sticky>
       </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Comment: If there is no option to disable it, I think you have to implement yourself. Which behaviour are you expecting from `isActive` ?

Comment: I've added PR, I think it will be merged and released soon, https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/pull/2053

Comment: @AlexanderFedyashov, thank you, looking forward to the merge. The `active` props will come in handy when I want to disable sticky header on some pages but keep it on others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `active` prop for `Sticky` component is available from [`0.73.1`](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v0731-2017-09-18).